# Emacs freezes on long line wrapping of shell / REPL output

Tags: emacs

I have a constant problem with Emacs that it cannot handle the long line-wrapped printouts in RELP or shell mode. The Emacs process starts running on full CPU and is almost completely unresponsive (sporadically it start to process user commands but then freezes again). This means I have to kill the process and restart Emacs. Obviously, this is a major stability and usability problem, and **something which a normal terminal can easily handle**.

I am not using any esoteric line wrapping extensions, only the default `toggle-truncate-lines` is enabled (line wrapping is needed in shell or REPL). The Emacs version is `24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2)`.

Google search around the issue does not return anything useful or similar. Has no one else experienced these problems? Any solution or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long are those "long line"s?  Emacs is not good at handling long lines.

Comment: @Stefan "long lines" mean something like a printout of couple of hundred thousand of well-sized JSON objects in a lazy sequence, or maybe the 200,000th Fibonacci number. Nothing a good old `^C` would have problem with on a bare terminal.

Comment: Then it's a known problem: these lines are much too long for Emacs.  There are various ways to make them usable, but there are also various ways in which Emacs code doesn't work well for long-lines, so making them work acceptably often involves several tweaks.

Comment: @Stefan Emacs is quite often used as shell or REPL environment so I would categorize this issue as severe. I found [this](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=3219) bug report, and [another one](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16786). The later claims the issue did not exist back in version 21, only since 22 to 24, which could indicate it is not a fundamental flaw. It would be great to know the internal details around line wrapping and buffers, find the root cause, and hopefully get this fixed.

Comment: @Stefan Would you post some of your workarounds as answer in the meantime?

Comment: You can start by turning off `font-lock-mode` snice it refreshes the highlighting line-by-line.

Comment: I second the request for a solution to this problem.  Today accidentally I tried to paste onto an emacs shell some text copied from the firefox debugger via  Right Click + Copy Image Data-URL.  I didn't realized that the text copied was extremely long.  Emacs is displaying the text a few thousand characters at a time (every minute or so) and has been doing so for 9 hours with no end in sight.  I cannot interrupt it, scroll or do anything else.  I'd kill it but I have important earlier in the shell buffer.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Various parts of Emacs work "a line at a time", under the assumption that lines are not too long.  So long lines like the ones you describe tend to bring Emacs to its knees.

There ae often ways to reduce the pain, but it all depends on the specifics of your case, so without more details as to which major mode you're using (for example), the most obvious first thing to do is to turn off `font-lock-mode` since it rehighlights the text line-by-line (so after adding, say, 4KB of output to the end of the line, it reprocesses the whole line to highlight it, which in turns means the redisplay code then has to reprocess the whole line to see what part of highlighting might have changed).

Answer (score 0):

try Visual Line mode or obsoleted Long Lines mode in old version, should reduce CPU load significantly.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question.